# Installed winforms application from Installshield Limited Edition VS 2012 fails when try to open

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installation, installshield-le

I am currently working on a windows forms application in Visual Studio 2012, C#, .Net Framework 4.5.
The Solution contains one Mainapplication and four dlls. One of them is encapsulated and loaded with reflection. This one is also including the persistance with Entity Framework.

Now I wanted to install the application. I have tried that with Installshield Limited Edition. It works perfectly on the pc with Visual Studio. Then I have tried to install the application on an "naked" pc. The install worked, but when I am trying to open the application Windows says that the application isn't working anymore and if I'd like to send the error to Microsoft. There is no error message or anything else.

Anybody an idea? 
Is it possible to install on pc's without VS with a setup from Installshield LE at all?

thanks for help.

Comment: Take a look in your Event Viewer. It might give you some clues as to why it's not working, maybe even a stack trace. As to why InstallShield isn't installing it correctly, I don't know. But at least if you find out why the application isn't running, you can investigate that.

Comment: Not taking care of properly reporting unhandled exceptions is a very common oversight.  Write an event handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.  Log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString() so you know what went wrong.